# Does Jekyll support backticks code blocks now?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When I read the official documentation, it only mentioned the `{% highlight python %}` syntax:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

However I prefer to use the backticks code block to highlight codes in markdowns:

````
```python
    code goes here
```
````

I googled around and found a few requests but I'm not sure if the backticks work right now. If it works, how can I enable it? As I experimented with my own jekyll github page and it still only works with `{% highlight python %}`.

---

It seems that the kramdown is only on Jekyll 3.X. Unfortunately, the theme that I'm using is on 2.X.

https://cecilialee.github.io/

How can I work on it? Would I be able to update my theme to Jekyll 3.X without breaking anything? Or how can I add the function to my current Jekyll site?

Comment: IT should considering https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/f3300c177258e656d642a6d36c4b868c9706f70c/lib/theme_template/README.md.erb. And https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6448. See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/a20d13d6b5fa6167f8a87f5a7aecbe20214e6c15/docs/_docs/upgrading/2-to-3.md

Answer (score 2):

Yes backticks and `~` also work for highlighting code without further configuration. Jekyll uses Kramdown by default which supports *backtick fenced code blocks*.

Following your example:

````
```python
fun test_me():
    print('yes, backticks work!')
```
````

produces:

```
<div class="language-python highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code><span class="n">fun</span> <span class="n">test_me</span><span class="p">():</span>
    <span class="k">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s">'yes, backticks work!'</span><span class="p">)</span>
</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that the kramdown is only on Jekyll 3.X. Unfortunately, the theme that I'm using is on 2.X.

https://cecilialee.github.io/

How can I work on it? Would I be able to update my theme to Jekyll 3.X without breaking anything? Or how can I add the function to my current Jekyll site?